# Laravel eloquent query where like relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

My database skills aren't the best and I'm looking for help in constructing a query in Laravel.

I have a table A and table B, table A has a field referencing fields in table B

So I could do `$tableA->tableB->title`

What I want is something like `$tableA->tableB->where('title', 'LIKE', $query)->get()`

What I want to do is do a `WHERE LIKE` and return the table A results but to search within table B in a specific column (for this example the column is title).

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code. No one is here to write code for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please try this way,

```
    $posts = ModelA::whereHas('modelb', function ($query) {
         $query->where('title', 'like', 'foo%');
    })->get();
```

Comment: Is there a way to chain this to multiple whereHas?

Comment: yes you can chain multiple whereHas, please note that if you are working with a related model of related model of parent, in this case modelb, then you will use dot notation..